# Is this version of the Real Spectral Theorem phrased incorrectly or am I just not reading the question correctly?

Tags: linear-algebra

The Theorem in the textbook states the following:

> If $A$ is an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix, then the following is true:
>
> - $A$ is diagonalizable.
> - All eigenvalues of $A$ are real.
> - If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of A with multiplicity $k$, then $\lambda$ has $k$ linearly independent eigenvectors. That is, the eigenspace of $\lambda$ has dimension $k$.

"In Exercises 7-10, prove that the symmetric matrix is diagonalizable." Well, if the matrix is symmetric, what is there to prove, if the above theorem is the reasoning alone? I do not think I am understanding correctly.

Comment: I edited your post to make it more readable.  In particular, putting a > before each line gives the yellow box.

Comment: Perhaps they want you to find a specific invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got it right; the theorem looks correct to me so long as it's talking about matrices with real entries, and it does say that any (real) symmetric matrix is diagonalizable. Without seeing the textbook, I'm not sure if the authors want you to

- explicitly diagonalize the matrix,
- just cite the theorem, or
- prove the theorem as a series of exercises.